# Como pegar somente uma informação desta tabela? VB.NET

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Olá, tenho essa tabela, que não possui class, id ou name.  gostaria de pegar somente o telefone dela.

como seria possível pegar?

```
<tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">name</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">99 999999999</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">xxxxxxx@hotmail.com</a></td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez, seja algo do tipo:

```
Dim TDUM As String
Dim TDDOIS As String
Dim TDTRES As String
Dim TDQUATRO As String
Dim count As Integer = 0

Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(codigo.text, "<a[^<>]*>")
    For Each match As String In substrings
                Dim aryTextFile = match.Split("</a>")
                If count = 2 Then
                    TDUM = aryTextFile(0)
                ElseIf count = 3 Then
                    TDDOIS = aryTextFile(0)
                ElseIf count = 4 Then
                    TDTRES = aryTextFile(0)
                ElseIf count = 5 Then
                    TDQUATRO = aryTextFile(0)
                End If
                count += 1
            Next

count = 0
```

Seria mais ou menos isso, estou estudando, então com certeza há códigos menores por aí, porém consegui chegar até este código no momento.

Para as pessoas que entendem, me desculpe o código grande e bagunçado (:

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma boa idéia um elemento sem identificadores,  mas supondo que esse seja o melhor caso.. (única tabela no DOM, sempre com essa quantidade de colunas), pode usar o jQuery:

```
$('table').find ('td').eq(3);
```

Comment: Na realidade, seria VB.NET, desculpe. acho que houve algum erro.